# cannot find screen session I detached from

Tags: gnu-screen, unix-sockets

I am running a program on Unix server and I am mindful that I detached the screen and logged out of the server. Later I `ssh`'d back in and tried to reattach but I just cannot find my screen.

In fact `screen -ls` returns - *there are no sockets running*

The program seems to be running as it is updating some files and my overall folder space is reducing as it is supposed to as confirmed via the `du -sh` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo find /var/run/screen -type s
```

That will list the open sessions, with the user name (in case you created, for example, the session under sudo).

With that information, from the right user, you can recover your lost session.